# Transition between planes

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I want to create a landscape with multiple planes and sculpting. I want to have a transition between the planes so I don't have a gap or overlap planes.

Could someone please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to Edit - Preferences... Add-ons tab and search for **LoopTools**. Enable the add-on.
2. Select both objects and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>J</kbd> to join them.
3. hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> and click right to the right edge of the left plane. THen hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> and click left to the left edge of the right plane.
4. Right click and choose LoopTools -> Bridge

[image: 1]

4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, hover over the bridge and use your mouse wheel to get  a uniform density of loops across whole mesh.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Edge Menu > *Bridge Edge Loops* does a lot more than bridge edge loops.

With these sort of settings:

[image]

...it makes a very nice interpolation between adjacent surfaces:

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know about this interpolation feature!